# Facebook Like Box Custom Content

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

the idea is i'm trying to get rid of specific posts from Facebook Like Box, can i do that? 
i don't want to remove it from actual Facebook post, i just want to remove it from Facebook Like Box, i already search it for like two days but still stuck

in my opinion the only method i only get is to remake Facebook Like Box and put filtered post into the content, is there any other ways?

here's my code :

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fxxxx&amp;width&amp;height=495&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;header=true&amp;stream=true&amp;show_border=true&amp;appId=294912324023652" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:360px; height:495px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

help me please
thanks

Comment: Your Facebook like box code is a twitter timeline? My guess is that that could be the problem.

Comment: oops, my bad, copy pasted the wrong code, sorry i already fixed it